# How can I test Chrome's "remember password" prompt on my site to make sure it's working?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

I'm working on a site that uses an XHR to authenticate the user and is supposed to trigger the password save prompt by using `history.pushState` but it's not working. I thought I was doing something wrong, but then I saw my normal form without using any JavaScript was also not working. Is there any way to consistently trigger the password save dialog to make sure I'm doing everything correctly, at least in some kind of development or staging environment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what causes the Chrome to be inconsistent with when it shows the password prompt when I'm using it when logged into my Google account, but I created a new user and it started working pretty much every time I entered the password. Maybe the problem is being caused by an extension I have installed or something.

So if anyone comes across this issue try adding a new Chrome user that isn't logged in with a Google account.